# Nginx static page curl works but browser doesn't work

Tags: nginx, web

I am using digitalOcean vps to setup Nginx(the default one). I can use `curl xxx.com` on the server and get the content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I try to access xxx.com from browser it doesn't work.

Here is the conf file:

**nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;

worker_processes auto; # 4
worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}


http {
         server {
              listen         80;
              server_name xxx.com www.xxx.com;
              root /usr/share/nginx/html;
              index index.html index.htm;
              location / {
               # proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9001;
                #index index.html index.htm;
              }
                #return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
         }


        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
       

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

      
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

      

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

gzip on;

}
```

Any help? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling few hours, the final reason is the firewall doesn't open 80 port.
`sudo ufw status verbose`
check no 80 port there.

`sudo ufw allow 80` did it.